# IIS Configuration - Root Site with applications

Tags: iis-7

It's difficult to explain this one. I want to setup a site which has a number of applications underneath it in IIS7. Basically I want a URL for a site like this for the root site:

```
mysite.domain.com
```

But I also want to host an application underneath this such as:

```
mysite.domain.com/test
```

This "test" instance shouldn't inherit anything from the parent's web.config at all. They must belong to the same site because the DNS is configured as such (unless I'm mistaken, and you can configure the DNS differently).

Any ideas on how you can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can turn off configuration inheritance from the root per se, but the web.configs in the root of the sub-applications can overwrite or clear most of the settings done in the root web.config.

For appSettings, connectionStrings and other multiple children nodes, you can use

```
<clear />
<remove ... />
```

for single occurrence settings, just set a new value.

I don't think you can overwrite or remove 'configSections', but that should not be a problem.